# How to add a node in the middle of the line with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

How do I add in the middle of the line a node with Tikz? I want somethink like this:

```
-------------->
     text
```

Normally I did it with an additional `node at` command. If I will resize the the arrow then I need to change the position of the node also.

```
---------->
   text
```

Which is not the best way for big things. I try to find something in the manual and didn't find an answer yet.

Thanks.

Best regards.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You could also use the `midway`-option

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [->] (0,0) -- (5,0) node [midway, below] {Text};
    \draw [->] (0,1) -- (5,1) node [near end, below] {Text};
    \draw [->] (0,2) -- (5,2) node [pos=0.62, below] {Text};
    \draw [->] (0,3) -- (5,3) node [pos=0.2, below] {Text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: result of the given example]

See the tikz manual section **16.8 “Placing Nodes on a Line or Curve Explicitly”** …

Comment: Note that if you use curved arrows, this solution will not work (the text does not end up in the middle of the arrow). You will have to use something like `\draw[->,>=stealth,out=90,in=90] (A) to node[midway,above] {Text} (B) ;`

Comment: Thanks a lot @AnthonyLabarre

Answer (score 26):

You can use the `node` construct without the `at` specifier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->] (0,0) --  node[label= below:text] {} (2,0);
  \draw[->] (0,1) --  node[label= below:text] {} (3,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]