# reposition label of a line

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code draws a vector and places a label on it

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (v1) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (v2) at (1,1);
  \draw[->] (v1) -- node[right] {$\vec{a}$} (v2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with the output

[image]

How can I reposition the label along the vector line up, down, left, right?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17136/how-to-add-a-node-in-the-middle-of-the-line-with-tikz/17157#17157?

Comment: The node is currently `right` of `midway` of the line.  Do you mean (1) to *slide* it closer to the start or the end of the line (that would use the `pos=<proportion>`key) or (2) to *shift* how much `right` it is (that would be the `right=<distance>` key) ? Or something else I don't understand yet ?

Comment: Try `pos` as in `\draw[->] (v1) -- (v2) node[right,pos=0.3] {$\vec{a}$};`.

Comment: Solutions such  as node[right=5pt,pos=0.3] appear to work

Comment: You also have a bunch of positions such as `(very )near start`, or `at end`. If you wish, you can change how much the `right` modifier shifts for the whole picture by writing `\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5pt]` or the same for just a `\begin|end{scope}`.

Answer (score 5):

As already mentioned in the comments, position along the lines can be done as fraction of path length with `[pos=]` or with names in variation of `at start`, `very near start` … `midway`. See section 17.8 of the `pgf` bible for details and definitions of the named positions. With the `positioning` package, you can make definitions such as `right= of a`, where `a` may be a coordinate or node. `label=right:object` allows for labels to be set next to nodes, taking size and shape of the to be labelled object into account. (section 17.10.2) The `positioning` library also allows implicit placement, even iteratively. Chapter five explains this quite well.

Positioning of the label relative to its origin can be done via `left`, `right`, `above` and `below`, combinations thereof such as `above right` (order does not matter). Equivalently, you can use `north`, `south` and so on. If you do not feel satisfied, you can further manipulate the position via `xshift`, `yshift` or the combination `shift={,}`. I hope this helps you to get your label exactly where you want it.